# Different combinations of 7 books distributed to 7 critics, twice

Tags: combinatorics

I'm having an exam on Discrete Mathematics II in my university, and I came up to this problem.

> A publishing firm has 7 books ready to publish. Each of them needs to be reviewed by 2 different critics, so the firm hires 7 critics.
>   In the first week, each book is distributed to a critic, then in the second week, the books are rearranged.
>   In how many ways can we arrange the books so that no critic receives the same book twice?

I thought the question was straightforwardly asking for me to apply the perturbation formula for successive combinations. So I wrote down the solutions as:

$Dn = n!(1-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-...+(-1)^n\frac{1}{n!})$ and applied for $n=7$.

**My problem is that this feels wrong**. I never used the information that our critics are 7 in number, or that the reviews needed are two.
What would happen if each book needed 3 or 4 reviews? The result of the formula would obviously need to be smaller, but there's only one variable used in it.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: You have certainly used the fact that there are $7$ reviewers when you say "applied for $n=7$"! Also, are you aware on the principle of inclusion/exclusion (PIE)? You're essentially done, but I hope this helps put your mind at ease!

Comment: Check $n = 4$. Consider the sample space of $4$-tuples $S = \{(1, 2, 3, 4), (1,3,2,4), ..\}$. Let $A_i$ be the subset whose $i$th component is $i$, i.e. $A_1 = \{(1, 2, 3, 4), .., (1, 4, 3, 2)\}$. Then$$n(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4) = n(A_1) + n(A_2) + n(A_3) + n(A_4) - n(A_1 \cap A_2) - n(A_1 \cap A_3) - n(A_1 \cap A_4) - n(A_2 \cap A_3) - n(A_2 \cap A_4)  -n(A_3 \cap A_4) + n(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) + n(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4) + n(A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_4) + n(A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4) - n(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4)$$Each is easily ascertained. Then $4! - n(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4) $

Comment: We can extrapolate for $n = 7$. Notice that there are $C(7,i)$ ways of selecting $i$ intersections, that is $A_{j_1} \cap .. \cap A_{j_i}$, each with $(7 - i)!$ elements. Then $$n(A_1 \cup .. \cup A_7) = C(7,1)(7 - 1)! - C(7,2)(7 - 2)! + C(7,3)(7 - 3)! - C(7,4)(7 - 4)! + C(7,5)(7 - 5)! - C(7,6)(7 - 6)! + C(7,7)(7 - 7)! = 3186$$ We're interested in $7! - 3186 = 1854$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not absolutely clear what the question asks us to count. But my interpretation is that we are asked for the total  number of allowed assignments.

In the first round, the books can be assigned in $7!$ ways. For each of these ways, there are $D_7$ allowed second round assignments, for a total of $7!D_7$.

Comment: I think it is fairly clear, and you interpreted it as I did. In any case, it seems to me that the only other sensible interpretation would just be $D_7$, so it isn't a big deal.

Comment: If a reviewer reviews book 1 in the first round and 2 in the second round vs reviewing book 2 in the first round and book 1 in the second round - are these counted as one or two instances?

Comment: @Muralidharan: The interpretation I used for the count treats them as different. This may make practical sense, the first book read may influence one's opinion of the second.

Comment: @AndréNicolas It is interesting to count the number of ways if these two instances are treated as 1.

Comment: @Muralidharan: Yes, I would agree that it makes for a nicer problem. Particularly  if you feel that is a good interpretation, perhaps you should post an answer based on that.